# How to get a selected value from a javascript ( event ) object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select, jquery-events

I am trying to get the selected value from an event.

I don't know which method to get this value. Any suggestions ?

```
//update item quantity
cartList.on('change', 'select', function (event) {
   var row = $(event.target).parents('.product');
   updateItemQuantity(row.data('row_id'), QUANTITY_IS_SELECTED_VALUE);
   quickUpdateCart();
});
```

Comment: `event.target.value`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get selected value in dropdown list using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/get-selected-value-in-dropdown-list-using-javascript)

Comment: yes, i just realized ( event.target is the element that triggered the event )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`event.target` is the element that triggered the event. You can read its value using jQuery by doing `$(event.target).val()`. You can also use the `this` keyword, which holds the same element (`$(this).val()`).

Instead of using jQuery, you could also retrieve the value through the vanilla DOM method of `this.options[this.selectedIndex].text`.

Comment: `event.target.value` and `this.value` avoids a jQuery instantiation and a `val()` method invocation.  If you already have the variable, direct property access can be more performant.

Comment: @Taplar True, and I would normally use vanilla `.value` instead, but it doesn't work everywhere for selects - in older browsers you would have to use the selectedIndex workaround. I'll update my answer to mention it however.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
event.target.options[event.target.options.selectedIndex].text
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25649492)

Comment: I was looking for the same and didn't found here the solution without jquery. so thought to share how i got it without jquery.

Answer (score 0):

The `.val()` method in jQuery returns or sets the value attribute of the selected elements.This method returns the value of the value attribute of the FIRST matched element.

```
 $(selector).off('change').on('change', function () {
    var selectedValue = $(this).val();
    alert(selectedValue);
    //Your other logic here
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

With pure `javascript` you can find selected option and all related information:

```js
console.log(event.target.selectedOptions[0].value);
console.log(event.target.selectedOptions[0].label);
```

Answer (score 0):

you could target the Select by class, then add an onChange handler, and get the value

```
var selectItem = document.querySelector("select.cartList");
selectItem.addEventListener("change", function(event) {
    var newChangedValue = event.target.value;
    console.log(newChangedValue);
});
```